# Como fazer uma barra de progresso circular para web?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Como essa da imagem anexada abaixo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Da uma olhada nesse site, analisando o fonte vai notar que é bem simples criar com css puro. http://www.cssscript.com/demo/pure-css-circular-percentage-bar/

Comment: @LucasLima este exemplo usa propriedades depreciadas do css por exemplo a propriedade clip

Comment: Queira postar o que tentou fazer e a dificuldade exata.

Comment: Seria bom tambem um trecho de código e um contexto onde vai ser usado isso, para que a resposta possa resolver o problema de fato.

Comment: Olá, Bacco. O Lennon já respondeu o que eu queria saber.

Comment: Fica a dica pra por os detalhes nas próximas, pq imaginemos que a resposta dele não te servisse por algum detalhe, ai seria tempo perdido das duas partes. Quanto mais detalhes nas próximas, melhor. Que bom que nesse caso deu certo.

Comment: Entendo, obrigado pela dica.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vou contribuir..

```js
var el = document.getElementById('graph'); // get canvas

var options = {
    percent:  el.getAttribute('data-percent') || 25,
    size: el.getAttribute('data-size') || 220,
    lineWidth: el.getAttribute('data-line') || 15,
    rotate: el.getAttribute('data-rotate') || 0
}

var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var span = document.createElement('span');
span.textContent = options.percent + '%';
    
if (typeof(G_vmlCanvasManager) !== 'undefined') {
    G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(canvas);
}

var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = canvas.height = options.size;

el.appendChild(span);
el.appendChild(canvas);

ctx.translate(options.size / 2, options.size / 2); // change center
ctx.rotate((-1 / 2 + options.rotate / 180) * Math.PI); // rotate -90 deg

//imd = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 240, 24a0);
var radius = (options.size - options.lineWidth) / 2;

var drawCircle = function(color, lineWidth, percent) {
  percent = Math.min(Math.max(0, percent || 1), 1);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(0, 0, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2 * percent, false);
  ctx.strokeStyle = color;
        ctx.lineCap = 'round'; // butt, round or square
  ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth
  ctx.stroke();
};

drawCircle('#efefef', options.lineWidth, 100 / 100);
drawCircle('#555555', options.lineWidth, options.percent / 100);
```

```css
div {
    position:relative;
    margin:80px;
    width:220px; height:220px;
}
canvas {
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
span {
    color:#555;
    display:block;
    line-height:220px;
    text-align:center;
    width:220px;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    font-size:40px;
    font-weight:100;
    margin-left:5px;
}

input {
    width: 200px;
}

span {
  
}
```

```html
<div class="chart" id="graph" data-percent="88"></div>
```

Agora só alterar o atributo `data-percent` para a porcentagem que você quiser.

Comment: Obrigado, Lennon.